# Scroll to SelectedItem WPF when the PropertyChanged event is raised

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im using WPF with MVVM.

My XAML view contains a listview bound to an ICollectionView. In my viewModel I handle an OnPropertyChange event to select that particular list view item when it's property changes. Then, I scroll to in from the view code behind.

The problem is the scroll is bound to Selection_Changed in the xaml so if the item that had its property changed is already selected it will not scroll to it.

How do I achieve the scrolling if the item is already selected?

Comment: Why do you need to change scroll position at all if the item is already selected?

Comment: The selected item can have it's property changed by other areas the of the application. Thus, the selected item might not be scrolled to already. In other words, the user cannot see the selected item that just had it's property changed in the listview

Comment: So handle the `PropertyChanged` event for the item and do whatever you currently do in your event handler then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I achieve the scrolling if the item is already selected?

Instead of handling the `SelectionChanged` event, you could for example handle the `PropertyChanged` event for the view model class where the property that is set is defined, e.g.:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;

        viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;

        ...
    }

    private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.SelectedItem))
        {
            // scroll...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does work, BUT I wanted to see if there was a way to to this without exposing the viewModel in the code behind

Comment: The view model is already "exposed" to the view so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Then you can directly change the selection inside the setter of whichever property you want to monitor and update the value of the `mySelectedItem` property to do this as well.

Comment: The view model doesn't know how to scroll in the view.